# How to iterate array while splicing

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array `INTERVALS` and I want to remove a subset of elements from this array. 
I tried using `for` loop and `splice`, but it is not working as desired. It seems the for loop should not modify the array. Any help?

```
function remove_intervals(list) {
  for(i=0; i < INTERVALS.length; i++) {
    var o = INTERVALS[i];
    if(o in list) {
      clearInterval(o);
      INTERVALS.splice(i,1);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It is typically an anti-pattern to iterate over an array that you are modifying inside the iteration

Comment: Ah looks the indexing is somehow the issue.. Any alternative? @Taplar

Comment: Consider a usage of filter.  Or consider iterating backwards, from the end to the beginning.

Comment: Oh iterating backwards doesn't disturb the indexing for splice. You're truely awesome! Thank you:) @Taplar

Comment: Iterating backwards does change the index, but not in a manner that you care, as it does not change the preceeding index that you will continue to process on.  The index after that point will change, but you don't care.  You've already processed past them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.filter` like this:

```js
function remove_intervals(list) {
    INTERVALS = INTERVALS.filter(id => {
        if (id in list) {
            clearInterval(id);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you do this using a the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [inccludes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) methods to create a new array

```js
const words = ['spray', 'limit', 'elite', 'exuberant', 'destruction', 'present'];
const toRemove = ['limit', 'elite', 'destruction'];

const result = words.filter(word => toRemove.includes(word));

console.log(result);
// expected output: Array ['spray', 'exuberant', 'present'];
```

Comment: Also, `in` operator looks for the property name, not for a value in an array.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're trying to do now